# Meaning of the notation $\partial_{\log x}$

Tags: notation, differentiation

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.07590.pdf), and there is the notation $\partial_{\log x}$ in (6.21) on page 17. What does this notation mean?

Comment: $\partial_a\equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial a}$. In this case, $a=\log x$ and so $\partial_{\log x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\log x}$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, thank you very much. This formula has another form (5.18) in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.08533v3.pdf). Do we have $x \partial_x = \partial_{log x}$?

Comment: Seems like this belongs on math.SE.

Comment: @heather $\partial_t$ and related notation are common to both mathematics and physics. The paper linked is a physics paper. If it's on topic to ask for clarification about notation in a physics paper, it is on topic here.

Comment: @JamalS, it may have been in a physics paper, but it is mathematical notation.

Comment: @heather Just look at the hundreds of questions under the notation tag; many of them involve notation shared by mathematicians and physicists, and they have been left here. And in this case, I think you'll sooner see a physicist use $\partial_{\log x}$ than a mathematician. I'm not saying it's a good question, but it doesn't need to be migrated. Either closed or left open here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often the following compact notation is adopted:
$$\partial_t = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$

In this case you have
$$
\partial_{\log x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial (\log x)}  = x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
$$